# Using c++ operators as slots in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, signals-slots

I'm wondering if it is possible (and how) to use c++ operators, for example (), [] as Qt slots.

It seems that the compiler is complaining about this simple code

```
class MainWindowDecorator : public QObject
{  Q_OBJECT
private:
//some variables

public slots:
    int operator[](int i)
    {
    return i;
    }
}
```

The error is the following:

```
Error: Not a signal or slot declaration
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the complain? In QtCreator I don't get any :S

Comment: Yes, what is the text of the error?

Comment: I tried `Q_SLOT int operator[](int);`. While that didn't cause a moc error, it seemed to still miss the slot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create slot wrapper that would call dedicated `operator`.

The problem is that `moc` parser disallows that definition, probably because it expects an identifier and not a keyword.

Comment: the act is that I would like to expose that method as slots because I've a library PythonQt which, in order to expose methods to a Python context, must have them declared as slots.

Comment: @linello Have you tried with Q_INVOKABLE? That also makes a method known to the metatype system.

Comment: Ok, the compiler is ok, but I don't have the expected result from PythonQt side and I get that the object is unindexable...anyway, thanks for your suggestion!